# Can This Schema Markup Be Improved?

Tags: schema, structured-data

If you were implementing schema markup for a local business that is a tour operator, what would you add to or change to the schema markup listed below. I generated this code from an online schema tool creator, but I don't know if it's really the best schema markup or not.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<a itemprop="url" href="www.downtownaustintours.com"><div itemprop="name">Austin Tours Inc</div>
</a>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">100 Congress Ave</span><br>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Austin</span>,
<span itemprop="addressRegion">Texas</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">78701</span><br>
<span itemprop="addressCountry">United States</span><br>
<span itemprop="phone">(512) 111-2222</span>
<div itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
<meta itemprop="latitude" content="30.263843"/>
<meta itemprop="longitude" content="-97.744655"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also, it appears there is the option to use the itemtype "http://schema.org/TravelAgency" instead of "http://schema.org/LocalBusiness." Any opinion on what I should go with? Is there a way to include "United States" in the schema markup without actually having it appear in the visible text on the page? Most businesses don't typically list "United States" in their addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Since schema.org/TravelAgency does not really accurately describe your business, I would recommend using the LocalBusiness schema and then getting more granular with the markup by using the "additionalType" property, like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/doc/Tour_operator" />
<a itemprop="url" href="www.downtownaustintours.com"><div itemprop="name">Austin Tours Inc</div>
</a>

<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">100 Congress Ave</span><br>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Austin</span>,
<span itemprop="addressRegion">Texas</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">78701</span><br>
<meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="United States" /><br>
</div>
<span itemprop="telephone">(512) 111-2222</span>

<div itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
<meta itemprop="latitude" content="30.263843"/>
<meta itemprop="longitude" content="-97.744655"/>  
</div>
</div>
```

And typically, the phone number is not nested within the PostalAddress schema, and the property is "telephone", not "phone".  You can use a meta tag for the country property, too, just as I did above.  So try that and test it and see if you like the results.  I hope that helps.

David

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this great explanation. I hadn't heard of the "additionalType" property before, but it looks like good additional markup that has been recognized by sSchema.org. Great analysis and insight. Thank you David!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can find all the LocalBusiness properties here https://schema.org/LocalBusiness and since you have a travel agency its preferable to use a TravelAgency type, you can find all its properties here https://schema.org/TravelAgency